# Handle command response in windows bash

Tags: windows, wmic

I'm writing a bash script that should restart a running process. I'm able to kill a process using the process name (pcm.exe). How ever, when i want to start the process, i want it to get the pcm.exe location from the earlier running process. This is because i don't know exactly where the program is located on different systems.

I have the following script:

```
wmic process where "name='pcm.exe'" get ExecutablePath /FORMAT:LIST
@taskkill /f /im pcm.exe >nul
@timeout /t 10 /nobreak >nul
@start h:/pandora/pcm.exe >nul
```

wmic successfully gets the PCM location:

```
ExecutablePath=H:\Pandora\PCM.exe
```

But how can i pass the response to a string and run @start (the path)?

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR -

Use the `set` command

## Details:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "zTargetImage=notepad.exe"
set "zBinLocation=0"

for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in ('wmic process where "name='!zTargetImage!'" get ExecutablePath^,ThreadCount /format:csv 2^>^&1') do (
    set "zBinLocation=%%A"
)

taskkill /f /im !zTargetImage! >nul 2>&1
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
if not "!zBinLocation!"=="0" (
    start "" "!zBinLocation!" >nul
)
```